# How to collect output of a custom phing task in a phing property?

Tags: phing

**Background**

I started with this open ended question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36602830/list-differences-between-two-directories-from-point-of-view-of-one-directory-by

Then tried this to solve it using phing's native utilities, but got stuck - [How to return a value from a phing target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36618678/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-phing-target)

**Now I am trying** to write a custom Phing task, as per https://www.phing.info/docs/guide/trunk/ch06s06.html. I tried echoing the list of files in this,  with an intention to somehow collect the same in a property when the task is called from the build xml -

```
<addedfiles message="Hello World" outputProperty="output"/>
```

But I found that an `outputProperty` attribute is not supported in the call from the build xml file.

Any pointers on how to do this, or to the other two questions would help a lot.

Comment: A note for those trying to use a custom phing task like a function (a reusable utility), the output variable's names need to be different across multiple calls to that phing property. I passed the name of the output variable as a parameter while calling the property, and used the same name to set the name of the output property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh it is simple. We can set a property within the custom task class like this -

```
$this->getProject()->setNewProperty('output', "hello world");
```

and it can be accessed in the build xml, after the task call, like this -

```
<addedfiles message="Hello World" />
<echo>See ${output}</echo>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your solution doing this

```
private $outputProperty;

public function setOutputProperty($str)
{
    $this->outputProperty = $str;
}
```

and then, when you catch the output

```
$this->getProject()->setNewProperty($this->outputProperty, "hello world");
```